# How do I stop sprites from overlapping?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have two different types of sprites coming down from the top of the screen. However, sometimes they come down at the same time and in the same position one overlapping the other. How do I fix this so that they do not overlap when coming down? I have heard about using intersectNode, but I am unsure of how to actually implement it.

Here is what my code looks like so far:

```
// function to spawn enemies
func SpawnEnemies(){
    var Enemy = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "brick1")
    Enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Enemy.size)
    Enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.brick
    Enemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.hero
    Enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.hero
    Enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Enemy.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

    var MinValue: CGFloat = 0.0
    var MaxValue: CGFloat = self.size.width
    var SpawnPoint = UInt32(MaxValue - MinValue)
    Enemy.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(SpawnPoint)), y: self.size.height)
    let ActionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let EnemyAction = SKAction.moveToY(-100 , duration: 7.0)
    Enemy.runAction(SKAction.sequence([EnemyAction, ActionDone]))

    self.addChild(Enemy)
}

func SpawnEnemies2(){
    var Enemy2 = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "brick2")
    Enemy2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Enemy2.size)
    Enemy2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.brick
    Enemy2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.hero
    Enemy2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.hero
    Enemy2.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Enemy2.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

    var MinValue: CGFloat = 0.0
    var MaxValue: CGFloat = self.size.width
    var SpawnPoint = UInt32(MaxValue - MinValue)
    Enemy2.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(SpawnPoint)), y: self.size.height)
    let ActionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let EnemyAction = SKAction.moveToY(-100 , duration: 7.0)
    Enemy2.runAction(SKAction.sequence([EnemyAction, ActionDone]))

    self.addChild(Enemy2)
}
```

Comment: How are you deciding the horizontal spawn point of these sprites? It sounds like you need to know what sprites currently exist, and where they are so you can spawn new ones in a different location. What does your code look like so far?

Comment: I added the code in the question description :)

Comment: So you could replace `arc4random_uniform(SpawnPoint)` with a function that looks through all the current enemies and keep getting a random number until it's not one that overlaps with an existing one. Or just move it left or right if it overlaps an existing one. Or you could shuffle a fixed list of spawn points and just take the next one off the list.